# flex FileReference save function trigger cancel event with xml file on google-chrome version 47.0.2526.106 m

Tags: xml, google-chrome, apache-flex, actionscript, flash-builder

I have been trying to save xml file using flex FileReference save function but that trigger cancel event rather than showing browser save as dialog with xml file on google-chrome version 47.0.2526.106 m. We can save file with other extensions but we cannot with .xml extension. We can save xml file with previous version of google chrome and other browsers as well. it seems that, this is the bug in chrome or may be i need to update my code?

This is the very simple example i tried which is not working on chrome V 47.0.2526.106 as well.

```
var personnel:XML = <employees>
<employee id='1187' lastName='Davis' firstName='Charles'>
    <office>CT</office>
    <dept>Marketing</dept>
</employee>
<employee id='3383' lastName='Jones' firstName='Kevin'>
    <office>NY</office>
    <dept>Sales</dept>
</employee>
<employee id='2946' lastName='Samuels' firstName='Elizabeth'>
    <office>CT</office>
    <dept>Engineering</dept>
</employee>
</employees>

// new node appended
personnel.appendChild( <employee id='4002' lastName='Suzuki' firstName='Kenji'>
                        <office>MA</office>
                        <dept>Sales</dept>
                    </employee> );


// convert xml to binary data
var ba:ByteArray = new ByteArray( );
ba.writeUTFBytes( personnel );

// save to disk
var fr:FileReference = new FileReference( );
fr.save( ba, 'filename.xml' );
```

note if i will change filename.xml to any other extension example filename.html will work.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with Chrome version 48.0.2564.82, saving files with an .xml or .zip extension from Flash works again.

As a Chromium developer explained, [".zip was unblocked intentionally... you should anticipate that, unfortunately, these may need to be blocked again"](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=576708#c55). There doesn't appear to be a list of file extensions which are considered "dangerous".

Answer (score -1):

Confirmed, on the latest Chrome (at least 47.0.2526.106 and 47.0.2526.111) saving files from Flash using FileReference works selectively depending on the file extension.

According to [this post](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=576708#c25) by a Chromium developer, it's "working-as-intended" and for some reason .xml is considered a "dangerous (executable) file type".

Suggested workarounds are using javascript to download the file or using a different file extension.

This behavior is also controlled by the "Protect you and your device from dangerous sites" option in Chrome advanced settings.

Comment: Thanks, yes i also just removed .xml extension so user can manually add extension in save as popup.